# How to remove duplicate items from vector<vector<int>>

Tags: c++, c++14

I am trying to solve [Combination II](https://leetcode.com/problems/combination-sum-ii/) which is similar to coin change problem with unique combinations and no infinite repetition of the coin.

e.g: `coins: {1,2,4}, amount = 3`
`{1,1,1,1}` or `{1,1,2}` not allowed as coin 1 frequency is one time.(A single coin will be used only one time)

`{1,1,4}` ,`amount=3`
`{1,1,2}` --> will be allowed as those two ones are from two different 1's coin.

**Working Code:** https://ide.geeksforgeeks.org/5fjEmsWXUr

```
class Solution {
public:
    vector<vector<int>> combinationSum2(vector<int>& candidates, int target) {
        
        sort(candidates.begin(), candidates.end());
        vector <vector <vector <int>>> dp(target+1);
        dp[0] = {{}};
        //traverse throuugh coins
        for (int i=0; i<candidates.size()-1; i++){
            // traverse through DP (amount -> 0 inclusive)
            for(int j = target; j>=candidates[i]; j--){ // just reverse it start with target and use target-coin amount to fill. In this way we are just adding current number not repeating the same no. infinite times as done in j = candidates[i] to target+1; 
                // order repetition will be there. 
                for(auto v: dp[j-candidates[i]]){
                    v.push_back(candidates[i]);                    
                    dp[j].push_back(v);
                } 
            }
        }
        return dp[target];        
    }
};
```

**Your input**

```
[10,1,2,7,6,1,5]
8
```

**Output**

```
[[1,2,5],[1,2,5],[1,1,6],[2,6],[1,7],[1,7]]
```

**Expected**

```
[[1,1,6],[1,2,5],[1,7],[2,6]]
```

In my case:

`[1,2,5]` is occurring twice and `[1,7]` also.

**I want to remove these duplicates.**
I know we can use `set` to store them. But I am facing issues in using `set` and making modification in the function return type.

Comment: if you use a `std::set` instead of `std::vector` it cannot contain duplicates. What issues did you encounter?

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number: I know I have to use set. It's just I am not comfortable in using set. Have to make modification in the code also and I was getting errors :'(.

Comment: set is probably most efficient, the other way is to not add anything if it is already there. e.g. use std::find_if. (Though for this example that could get too slow)

Comment: the function must return a `vector<vector<int>>` ? Then use a `set<vector<int>>` and only when you return it you create the vector

Comment: "Have to make modification in the code" sure you do. You cannot change the code without changing the code. "also and I was getting errors" please show the broken code and the errors

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a `std::set`. It is literally just about replacing the inner `vector` with `set`:

```
class Solution {
public:
    std::vector<std::vector<int>> combinationSum2(std::vector<int>& candidates, int target) {

        std::sort(candidates.begin(), candidates.end());
        std::vector<std::set<std::vector<int>>> dp(target+1);
        dp[0] = {{}};
        //traverse throuugh coins
        for (int i=0; i<candidates.size()-1; i++){
            // traverse through DP (amount -> 0 inclusive)
            for(int j = target; j>=candidates[i]; j--){ // just reverse it start with target and use target-coin amount to fill. In this way we are just adding current number not repeating the same no. infinite times as done in j = candidates[i] to target+1; 
                // order repetition will be there. 
                for(auto v: dp[j-candidates[i]]){
                    v.push_back(candidates[i]);                    
                    dp[j].insert(v);
                } 
            }
        }
        return {dp[target].begin(),dp[target].end()};        
    }
};
```

Only when returning the vector of vectors you need to transform the set and the `set` has not `push_back`, but `insert`.

Comment: When I tried using set. I was facing issue with return type in `dp[target]`; this last line `{dp[target].begin(),dp[target].end()}` ----> `vector<vector<int>>`.

Comment: @Pygirl I assumed you cannot change the return type

Comment: @Pygirl not sure what you mean. Works fine here: https://godbolt.org/z/En7Tf49re

Comment: @Pygirl There is no `list` in your code. `std::vector` has a constructor taking a range of elements.

Comment: @Pygirl overload 5 here: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/vector

Comment: @Pygirl be careful with terminology. There is no casting in this code. Its a matter of what you are used to. I find it painful that in python you never know for sure of what type something is and you have so little control over it

Comment: Sorry for using wrong terminology. I was just trying to say. make set result to vector form. I don't know what term to use :'( and sorry for the silly question just trying hard to translate the logic to code using cpp :'(